# react native fabric / turbo, using enum or type

Tags: react-native

I have an react native fabric native components.
I'm trying to have in the Javascript Specification file a enum or type as follow:
Im getting an error when running codegen when using SizeType in the NativeProps interface.

Error: A default enum value is required for "size"

Is there a way to use Enums or types like this?
(If i dont use SizeType in the NativeProps the codegen running with no error).

Appreciate your answer.

```js
import type { HostComponent } from "react-native";
import { ViewProps } from "react-native/Libraries/Components/View/ViewPropTypes";
import codegenNativeComponent from "react-native/Libraries/Utilities/codegenNativeComponent";

type SizeType = "s" | "m" | "l"

export interface NativeProps extends ViewProps {
  title: string;
  size: SizeType;
}

export default codegenNativeComponent<NativeProps>(
  "RTNButtonView"
) as HostComponent<NativeProps>;
```

i tries to use type or enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this issue using `WithDefault`

Your code should be like this:

```js
import type { HostComponent } from "react-native";
import { ViewProps } from "react-native/Libraries/Components/View/ViewPropTypes";
import codegenNativeComponent from "react-native/Libraries/Utilities/codegenNativeComponent";
import type { WithDefault } from 'react-native/Libraries/Types/CodegenTypes';

type SizeType = "s" | "m" | "l"

export interface NativeProps extends ViewProps {
  title: string;
  size?: WithDefault<SizeType, 'm'>;
}

export default codegenNativeComponent<NativeProps>(
  "RTNButtonView"
) as HostComponent<NativeProps>;
```

Note that the `?` mark is important when using `WithDefault`